# Dart-related editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations with "One Monokai" theme not working in VS Code. Why? How can I fix it?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to apply some configurations. I like to use the `one monokai theme` for VS Code.

I always do it like this, specifically for the language dart because many themes don't have very good support yet.

```json
  "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "rules": {
      "variable:dart": {
        "foreground": "#cecece"
      },
      "property:dart": {
        "foreground": "#56b6c2"
      },
      "annotation:dart": {
        "foreground": "#56b6c2"
      },
      "parameter.label:dart": {
        "foreground": "#E06C75"
      },
    }
    
  },
```

Here's some flutter code to test it with:

```dart
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const TestWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      child: const Text("Hello!")
    );
  }
}
```

Here's one dark pro without any customization in dart:

[image: one dark pro without customizations]

Here's one dark pro with the json config I pasted before:

[image: one dark pro with customizations]

Here's one monokai theme with and without customizations (because it looks the same)

[image: one monokai]

Another example with monokai night

[image: Monokai Night]

I installed these themes and it doesn't get applied in any:

- Monokai pro
- One Monokai
- Monokai Night Theme
- Flatland Monokai

This works like a charm in other themes like one dark pro, dark+, etc. But for some reason **in every monokai theme, this does not work**. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the theme doesn't support semantic tokens, you may need to change this setting from "configuredByTheme" to "true":

[image: Semantic Tokens settings]